# Select all in otpgroup plus outside elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have dropdown menu where I can select multiple statuses. There are also statuses under certain groups.

I'm trying to make it like if user click on group(otpgroup) label(title) this to select all child elements plus to have ability to select outside group elements in the same time.

Currently it is working and user can click multiple elements but the group select doesn't work.

Here is the html

```
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form class="center" action="" method="get">
        <div class="form-group">
     <select class="input-fields selectStatuses" name="status[]" multiple>
         <option value="all">All statuses</option>
         <option value="creating-tasks"> Creating tasks</option>
         <optgroup label="In Progress">
              <option value="ongoing">Ongoing</option>
              <option value="in-progress">In progress</option>
          </optgroup>
       </select>
</div>   
</form>
</div>
```

The JS part

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker();
        let oldValue = $('option[value="all"]').val();
        
        $('.selectStatuses').on('change', function(e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                
            if ($('option[value="all"]', this).is(':selected') && oldValue == "all") {
                $('option[value="all"]', this).prop('selected', false);
                $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker('refresh');
                oldValue = "";
            } else if ($('option[value="all"]', this).is(':selected')){
                $(".selectStatuses").val(["all"]);
                $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker('refresh');
                 oldValue = "all";
            }
        });
    });
```

I have tried to add a class to the group `.select-all-group` and then target it in the JS like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker();
    let oldValue = $('option[value="all"]').val();

    $('.selectStatuses').on('change', function(e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();

        if ($('option[value="all"]', this).is(':selected') && oldValue == "all") {
            $('option[value="all"]', this).prop('selected', false);
            $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker('refresh');
            oldValue = "";
        } else if ($('option[value="all"]', this).is(':selected')){
            $(".selectStatuses").val(["all"]);
            $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker('refresh');
            oldValue = "all";
        }
    });

    // Select all child elements when group title is clicked
    $('.select-all-group').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).find('option').prop('selected', true);
        $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
});
```

But this produce the following error when page load:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': The token provided must not be empty.

Here is working demo that I have so far: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e2r6jqbL/)